# how to retrieve firebase data in bootstrap carousel

Tags: reactjs

I have a firebase table and i would like to have those datas in the bootstrap carousel with 3 cards in a slide using reactjs
Following is my table structure.

```
Employer1
     Job1
       Title
       Description
       Rate
     Job2
       Title
       Description
       Rate
```

Comment: Uh, its a bit too complex question. Please, try to research solutions for: 1. firebase-react integration, 2: setting up a react app, 3: dynamic element creation in react. If you have some more specific question while implementing, feel free to ask again.

Comment: i have set up a react app...and i implemented the firebase in it... all i wanted is to know how to use map to dynamically create elements and how to store firebase data in it...:)

Comment: Do you use redux state management, or prefer without?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a pattern like this: The `JobList` component is only responsible for displaying the list which gets via props. Its container is responsible for the server connection. It can be changed to a redux container too in case.
The firebase connection is a subscription which updates the jobs whenever they change on the db.

**JobList.js**

```
class JobList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { jobs } = this.props;

    return (
      <ul>      
        {jobs.map(({title, description, rate}) => (
          <li>
            <span>{title}</span>
            <span>{description}</span>
            <span>{rate}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

**JobListContainer.js**

```
class JobListContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    jobs: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    firebase.database().ref('/jobs')
    .on('value', this.updateJobs)
  }

  updateJobs = data => {
    if (data.val()) {
      this.setState({ jobs: data.val() })
    }  
  }

  render(){
    const { jobs } = this.state;
    return (<JobList jobs={jobs} />
  }

}
```